# Kohana 3 - Rendering image

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I have 1 controller to load and render the image.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Image extends Controller {

    public function action_topo($id=NULL) {

        $fornecedor = ORM::factory('provider')
            ->where('nometag', '=', $this->request->param($id))
            ->find();

        if ($fornecedor->loaded()) {
            $local = 'media/fornecedor/' . $fornecedor->nometag . '/' . $fornecedor->sis_foto_baner;            
            $image = Image::factory($local);
            $data = $image->render(NULL, 75);
        } else {
            $this->request->redirect('index');
        }

    }

}
```

It simple. In my URL /image/topo/name_of_company

When i load the page nothing happen! Where is the problem?

obs: iam new into frameworks.

tks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem lays in this line:

```
public function action_topo($id = NULL) {
```

and

```
->where('nometag', '=', $this->request->param($id))
```

Before 3.2 you could use either `$id` or `$this->request->param('id')` but certainly not `$this->request->param($id)` (well technically you could but it would give unexpected results).

Since 3.2 you should do it like this:

```
public function action_topo() {
   $id = $this->request->param('id');
   $fornecedor = ORM::factory('provider')
            ->where('nometag', '=', $id)
            ->find();
```

Comment: Tks, and the render? Why i cant render the image?

Comment: Well you don't do anything with the rendered image... I suppose you could try to show the image by setting the response body: `$this->response->body($image->render(NULL, 75));` or passing the image to associated view.